# Does this operator have a continuous, localized eigenfunction with negative eigenvalue?

Tags: mp.mathematical-physics, operator-theory, sp.spectral-theory, schwartz-distributions

I am looking at a class of operators
$$
L[f](x)=af_{xxxx}-bf_{xx}+\frac{d}{dx}(\delta(x)f_x)
$$ , a<0,b<0,
on the real line, where $\delta$ is Dirac-delta.

**I am interested in ruling out the possibility that this operator has a continuous localized eigenfunction with negative Eigenvalue.
Localized means it goes to 0 as $|x|\rightarrow \infty$.**

Away from origin, a candidate is
$$
v(x)=c\exp(-k|x|)
$$ for some appropriate $k$. However, when looking at its behavior near origin, if I compute
$$
\int_{-\epsilon}^{\epsilon}\frac{d}{dx}(\delta(x)v_x)dx=\frac{1}{2\epsilon}(v_x(\epsilon)-v_x(-\epsilon))=\frac{1}{2\epsilon}(2c),
$$ the term blows up as $\epsilon\rightarrow 0$ Hence we conclude no continuous localized eigenfunctions exist. Here I have approximated Dirac-delta by a constant function of width $w=2\epsilon$ and height $1/w$.

On the other hand, if I consider a discontinuous candidate
$$
v(x)=\operatorname{sign}(x)\cdot c\exp(-k|x|),
$$
the limit of the same integral is now = $ \frac{1}{2\epsilon}(v_x(\epsilon)-v_x(-\epsilon))=\frac{1}{2\epsilon}(c-c)= 0$. Hence, this candidate is a localized eigenfunction.

Is the above logic accurate or am I missing something ? What do i need to make the above rigorous ?

*******Some more details upon answer from Johannes Hahn and Michael Renardy*****

In general, $k\in \{ \pm \sqrt{\frac{b\pm\sqrt{b^2+4a\lambda}}{2a}} \}$, and solution  $f$ has the form
$$f(x) = \begin{cases} \sum_{i=1}^4 c_i e^{k_i x} & x<0 \\ \sum_{i=1}^4 d_i e^{k_i x} & x>0\end{cases}$$, where we can solve independently for $x<0$ and $x>0$.

However, we need $\lambda<0$. By looking at the expression for $k$ above, we see that since $a<0,b<0,\lambda<0$, $\sqrt{b^2+4a\lambda}>|b|$, which implies that
two of the $k$s will be imaginary (for both positive and negative $x$).

Let $r=k^2$. Then $r_1=\frac{b-\sqrt{b^2+4a\lambda}}{2a}>0$ and $r_2=\frac{b+\sqrt{b^2-4a\lambda}}{2a}<0$.
Hence, $k_{1,2}=\pm \sqrt{r_1}$ and $k_{3,4}=i\sqrt{-r_2}$.

However localization requires that only real $k$ terms survive since imaginary $k$ terms will give rise to $cos$ and $sin$ that don't decay at infinity. This implies $c_3=c_4=d_3=d_4=0$. Hence the candidate solution is reduced to:

$$f(x) = \begin{cases} \sum_{i=1}^2 c_i e^{k_i x} & x<0 \\ \sum_{i=1}^2 d_i e^{k_i x} & x>0\end{cases}$$

Furthermore, only positive $k$ is allowed for $x<0$ and negative $k$ for $x>0$ otherwise solution blows up as $|x|\rightarrow \infty$. This further implies $c_2=d_1=0$.  This leaves us with only two options as mentioned earlier:

Continuous candidate: $\cdot c\exp(-k|x|)$,

and

Discontinuous candidate: $\operatorname{sign}(x)\cdot c\exp(-k|x|)$, where $c=c_1=d_2.$

Comment: SInce $v(x)$ is discontinuous at the origin, $v'(x)$ contains a delta function. So $\delta(x)v'(x)$ is not even defined.

Comment: @MichaelRenardy Is it defined in what people call "Weak/measure-valued sense" ? For the purpose of this questions, lets replace it with a very sharp Gaussian.

Comment: Physically, we can think that term as a point perturbation in the diffusivity/diffusion coefficient of a certain medium.

Comment: Please check your signs. You are asking for a negative $\lambda$ with $Lf=\lambda f$, i.e. $af_{xxxx}-bf_{xx}-\lambda f=0$. For $e^{-kx}$ to be a solution, we need $ak^4-bk^2-\lambda=0$. If $a>0$, $b<0$ and $\lambda<0$ as you say, this is impossible for positive $k$. If you want people to spend time on solving this problem, please state it correctly.

Comment: @MichaelRenardy Thank you for pointing that out. You are right, the conditions had an error. It should read $a<0,b<0,\lambda<0$. I am sorry for the confusion.

Answer (score 1):

If $f$ is smooth, then $\delta \cdot f = f(0)\delta$ and consequently $(\delta \cdot f')' = f'(0) \delta'$. If $f$ is at least $C^1$ we can take this as the definition of the term. If $f$ is not $C^1$ around zero, then what does $\delta\cdot f'$ even mean?

Anyway, if it is at least $C^1$, then we can rearrange the eigenfunction equation
$$\lambda f = af^{(4)}-bf'' + f'(0)\delta'$$
to $f'(0)\delta' = -af^{(4)} + bf''+\lambda f$. Because, you're interested in the behaviour of $f$ at infinity, we can simply solve the ODE $0=-af^{(4)} +bf'' + \lambda f$ away from zero. Such an $f$ is an arbitrary linear combination of the functions $e^{k x}$ with $k$ one of the roots of $aX^4 - bX^2 - \lambda =0$, i.e. $k\in \{ \pm \sqrt{\frac{b\pm\sqrt{b^2+4ab\lambda}}{-4a}} \}$ (at least generically. For special values of $\lambda$, the general solution will look different)

We get to choose the coefficients of this linear combination independently on the right and left half of the real line, so that $f$ has the form
$$f(x) = \begin{cases} \sum_{i=1}^4 c_i e^{k_i x} & x>0 \\ \sum_{i=1}^4 d_i e^{k_i x} & x<0\end{cases}$$
for some $c_i, d_i$ of our choosing. In order for $f$ to be continuous, our choices have to satisfy $\sum_{i=1}^4 (c_i-d_i)=0$. In order for $f$ to be $C^1$ around zero, our choices have to satisfy $\sum_{i=1}^4 k_i (c_i-d_i)=0$. In fact, since we have eight degrees of freedom, we can make $f$ at least $C^4$ and also satisfy $f'(0)=0$ which makes the $\delta'$ term disappear and we have found an eigenfunction for the original operator.

Comment: Regarding your question, "what does $(\delta f')'$ even mean?", these operators with measure valued coefficients have been considered in (too) many papers, see for example here: https://arxiv.org/abs/1105.3755 The interpretations given are not always completely obvious though, and indeed it would be helpful if the OP provided more details on how $L$ is even defined.

Comment: @JohannesHahn   : Thanks. My original post skipped some details, but I basically followed the process you explain to get to the candidates in the original post. Note that for localization, we need further equations: We can only have real $k_i$ that will give rise exponential terms. The imaginary $k_i$ will give rise to cos and sin, which will not decay at infinity. Also, only specific signs of real $k_i$ are allowed to avoid blowup at infinity. With these conditions, we end up with only two possibilities as mentioned in original post, and one of them (the continuous one) leads to the blow-up.

Comment: @ChristianRemling Physically, we can think that term  as a point perturbation in the diffusivity/diffusion coefficient of a certain medium.

Comment: @johannesHahn: A further condition I missed is that eigenvalue is negative. That leads to conclusion in my previous coment. I have appended this to my post.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, such eigenfunctions exist.

If $a>0$, $b<0$ and $\lambda<0$, the roots $k$  of $ak^4-bk^2-\lambda=0$ are complex. Let $k_1$, $k_2$ be the roots with positive real part. Assume they are different; we can modify the calculation for the case when they are not. We are looking for an odd eigenfunction so that
$$f=c_1e^{-k_1x}+c_2e^{-k_2x},\, x>0,$$
$$f=-c_1e^{k_1x}-c_2e^{k_2x},\,x<0.$$
At the origin, we need $f=0$ and $a(f_{xx}(0+)-f_{xx}(0-))+f_x(0)=0$. This leads to
$$c_1+c_2=0,\,c_1(2ak_1^2-k_1)+c_2(2ak_2^2-k_2)=0.$$
For nontrivial solutions to exist, we require $2ak_1^2-k_1=2ak_2^2-k_2$. For $k_1\neq k_2$, this leads to $2a(k_1+k_2)=1$.
We also have $ak_1^4-bk_1^2=ak_2^4-bk_2^2$, which leads to $a(k_1^2+k_2^2)=b$. We now have two equations for $k_1$ and $k_2$, which yield complex solutions with positive real part as desired. Multiplying the last equation by $k_1^2$, we find $ak_1^4-bk_1^2=-ak_1^2k_2^2=\lambda$. Since $a$ is positive, and $k_1$ and $k_2$ are conjugates, this is indeed negative.

In the above analysis, I assumed $a>0$, $b<0$ and $\lambda<0$ as originally stated. Not all comments made here are consistent with this, so I cannot be sure this is what was intended.

Comment: unfortunately I made an error in sign of $a$, it should be $a<0$. My main concern with this question is the rule out the proposed continuous candidate and to see if the discontinuous candidate (both described original post) is an eigenfunction.

Comment: To balance the singularity at the origin, you need to balance $af_{xxxx}$ with $(\delta(x)f_x)_x$, i.e. $af_{xxx}$ needs to balance with $\delta(x)f_x$. For this to happen, $f$ and $f_x$ need to be continuous (if either is not, then $\delta(x)f_x$ is not defined as a distribution), and $f_{xx}$ needs to have a jump, leading to a delta function in $f_{xxx}$. As I pointed out above, this is possible with the signs as originally stated. It is not possible with the signs as stated now.

Comment: OK. Does that mean that the limit operation I have described in the original post is incorrect ?

Comment: Yes. $v_x$ is not the classical derivative. Rather, it is equal to the classical derivative plus $2c\delta(x)$, due to the discontinuity of $v$.